# GUID field in wp_posts - relevance for attachments?

Tags: attachments, guids

How significant is the guid field in wp_posts?

I'm doing a migration and adding a lot of images to the table (via `wp_insert_attachment, wp_generate_attachment_metadata and wp_update_attachment_metadata`), but the guid field isn't filled by default.

Should i correct this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to offer an ATOM feed for your attachments you should pass a GUID to `wp_insert_attachment()` or add a filter for `'get_the_guid'` that handles empty values. In most (all?) other cases I wouldn’t care about it.

Comment: but what is `guid` for ?

Comment: @FranciscoCorralesMorales See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier – it makes it possible to identify a resource.