# What is the proper use of guid for images in wp_posts?

Tags: posts, uploads, media, media-library, guids

I understand that `guid` is a unique reference for a post, whether that post is a `post` or an `attachment`.

When it's a post, I think guid is self-evident. But what is the correct formulation/destination for that URL when it is an attachment?

Should it point to the image file itself, or to the "post" page that WordPress stands up to render images?

If the latter, should the URL contain the slug of the `post_parent` (post to which it the image is attached), or not?

I am seeing a few different examples/options...

- `http://www.domain.com/wp-content/uploads/YYYY/MM/image.jpeg` (esp. if not attached?)
- `http://www.domain.com/YYYY/MM/slug-of-the-post/slug-of-the-image/`
  (esp. if attached?)

What is the value in it including the `post_parent` slug? This may be unnecessary?

If it's all personal choice as long as it's unique, well, what is WordPress' default behaviour?

Question not answered by similar:

- [GUID field in wp_posts - relevance for attachments?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15737/guid-field-in-wp-posts-relevance-for-attachments)
- [Set a custom URL for image in the Media Library?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/112659/set-a-custom-url-for-image-in-the-media-library)
- [Set Attachment Image File URL as GUID](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/213205/set-attachment-image-file-url-as-guid)

Comment: I wondered what makes you asked this question? Are you manually creating the attachment post, e.g. you upload the image using `wp_handle_upload()` and then manually call `wp_insert_post()`? Because core functions like `media_handle_upload()` and `media_handle_sideload()` will upload the media file (like an image) and create an attachment post for that media, so you don't need to worry about manually setting the GUID. And those core functions, including the REST API, default to using the file URL, which may look like `https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/02/image.jpg`.

Comment: Hi @SallyCJ I'm using `wp_update_attachment_metadata()` to update existing images' details (principally due to the file moving location) and also `wp_insert_attachment()` to add new such images from remote locations - the latter, with `file_get_contents()` and `file_put_contents()`. I am writing an image organisation plugin https://github.com/robertandrews/wp-tidy-media Do you think I should be using the `media_handle_*` functions? Thanks for pointing out the default format, which is to the file. I'm aware guid actually should not be changed, but they are wrong due to image moves.

Comment: The section ["Important GUID Note"](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/changing-the-site-url/#important-guid-note) in the WordPress documentation stated that GUID is "*a field that is intended to hold an identifier for the post which a) is unique across the whole of space and time and b) never, ever changes. The GUID field is primarily used to create the WordPress feeds*". It also says, "***Never, ever, change the contents of the GUID column, under any circumstances***".

Comment: So if you or the admin on the site where your plugin is used, *truly wants* to change the GUID *(which means they understand the consequences of doing so)*, then you can follow the default format (file URL). My understanding of the GUID though, is like our birth place - no matter where we are now, the fact that we were born in that place remains the same forever - i.e. we can lie, but the fact will never change...

Comment: Thanks for posting. I read that. This is for a site with changes so wide-ranging as to constitute a fresh, reborn site. Still curious what application `guid` has when the `wp_posts` type is `attachment` - what are feed readers doing with that? Also, should I be using the `media_handle_*` functions instead of `file_get_contents()`?

Comment: It's not common to have `attachment` posts in a feed, but one can create a custom WordPress feed showing media items in a gallery (with `guid` for each item), so I was just emphasizing what the documentation stated, as a heads-up. But what kind of answer were you hoping to get for this question; I thought the current answer is good, so didn't it already answered your question? And as for adding new images *from remote locations*, yes, I would use `media_handle_*` instead of `file_get_contents()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GUID is a unique identifier. That is its *only* purpose.

> When it's a post, I think guid is self-evident. But what is the
> correct formulation/destination for that URL when it is an attachment?

Attachments *are* posts. If the GUID is being used then the attachment is being consumed from a feed as a post. If attachments are not being distributed in a feed then the GUID is not probably not being used either.

If it's being used as a URL then it's being misused, and the permalink should be used instead.

> Should it point to the image file itself, or to the "post" page that
> WordPress stands up to render images?

It doesn't matter. It's only a unique identifier, it doesn't 'point' anywhere. The fact that it is a URL by default is merely the result of that being a shortcut method for creating a unique identifier, since URLs must be unique.

> If it's all personal choice as long as it's unique, well, what is
> WordPress' default behaviour?

By default the URL to the attached file is used as the GUID, at least as far as I can tell.

Comment: So, when I'm programmatically saving new images, I should always ensure the guid is straight to the file itself (eg. http://www.domain.com/wp-content/uploads/YYYY/MM/image.jpeg), rather than to the URL of the file's post (http://www.domain.com/YYYY/MM/slug-of-the-post/slug-of-the-image/)?

Comment: You shouldn’t need to set it at all. WordPress should do it automatically.